# Objective C Block Not Equal to Its Own Copy

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, objective-c-blocks

In my app, I associate an `NSTimer` with a block passed to a method; the block is also added to a an array of blocks. When the timer fires, its associated block is called and should be removed from the array. So my setup looks like this:

```
@interface MyObject : NSObject

@property(strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *allBlocks;

- (void)myMethodWithBlock:(void(^)(void))block;
- (void)timerFired:(NSTimer *)timer;

@end

@implementation MyObject

- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self)
    {
        self.allBlocks = [NSMutableArray array];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)myMethodWithBlock:(void(^)(void))block
{
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:5.0f
                                     target:self
                                   selector:@selector(timerFired:)
                                   userInfo:block
                                    repeats:NO];
    [self.allBlocks addObject:block];
}

- (void)timerFired:(NSTimer *)timer
{
    void(^block)(void) = timer.userInfo;
    [self.allBlocks removeObject:block];
    block();
}

@end
```

My problem is that when `timerFired:` is called, the block is (sometimes) not removed. Why?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you saving a copy of the block? In the sample you aren't using it for anything.

Answer (score 3):

The problem here is that `NSTimer` copies the block assigned to `userInfo`, but the block passed to `myMethodWithBlock:` is probably an instance of `NSStackBlock`, which is *not equal to its copies*.

Let's consider three scenarios, where `myObject` is an instance of `MyObject`:

```
// A
void(^myBlock)(void) = ^{
    NSLog(@"1");
};
[myObject myMethodWithBlock:myBlock];

// B
int one = 1;
void(^myBlock)(void) = ^{
    NSLog(@"%d", one);
};
[myObject myMethodWithBlock:myBlock];

// C
int one = 1;
[myObject myMethodWithBlock:^{
    NSLog(@"%d", one);
};];
```

- In **A**, the block captures no variables from its context; the block will be an instance of `NSGlobalBlock`, which simply returns itself when copied.
- In **B**, the block captures the variable `one`; it will be an instance of `NSMallocBlock`, which also returns itself when copied.
- In **C**, the block again captures the variable `one`, but is also *not assigned to a variable* before being passed to `myMethodWithBlock:`. In this case, the block is an instance of `NSStackBlock`, which returns an instance of `NSMallocBlock` when copied.

The result of this is that in a situation like scenario C, the `NSStackBlock` will be added to `allBlocks`, while an `NSMallocBlock` will be assigned to the timer's `userInfo`. When the timer fires, `removeObject:` does nothing since the block assigned to the timer isn't equal to any of the blocks in the array.

The solution is to always copy the block before storing it in the array. This way, the same block instance will be stored in the array and assigned to the timer:

```
- (void)myMethodWithBlock:(void(^)(void))block
{
    block = [block copy];
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:5.0f
                                     target:self
                                   selector:@selector(timerFired:)
                                   userInfo:block
                                    repeats:NO];
    [self.allBlocks addObject:block];
}
```

Comment: ASAIK you will have `NSStackBlock` in **B**. **B** and **C** are the same. You need to call `copy` to move block to the heap and create `NSMallocBlock`.

Answer (score 1):

A clearer approach is to mark the blocks with something whose `isEqual:` behavior is well known and more readable, like an `NSNumber`...

```
// keep state so these can be made unique
@property(nonatomic, assign) NSInteger blockIndex;
// change the blocks collection to record blocks' associations with numbers
@property(nonatomic, strong) NSMutableDictionary *allBlocks;

// in myMethod...
NSNumber *nextIndex = [NSNumber numberWithInt:++self.blockIndex];
self.allBlocks[nextIndex] = block;

// pass userInfo:nextIndex when you schedule the timer
```

Now the timer context never has a block, copied or otherwise.  Then, when the timer fires...

```
- (void)timerFired:(NSTimer *)timer {

    NSNumber *index = timer.userInfo;

    void(^block)(void) = self.allBlocks[index]; 
    [self.allBlocks removeObjectForKey:index];

    block();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it will be safest to compare apples to apples.

```
- (void)myMethodWithBlock:(void(^)(void))block
{
    NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:5.0f
                                                      target:self
                                                    selector:@selector(timerFired:)
                                                    userInfo:block
                                                     repeats:NO];
    [self.allBlocks addObject:timer.userInfo];
}

- (void)timerFired:(NSTimer *)timer
{
    [self.allBlocks removeObject:timer.userInfo];

    void(^block)(void) = timer.userInfo;
    block();
}
```